# Given two related tables, how to determine the most common relationships?

Tags: sql, mariadb, rds

given a 3 tables: users, books, book_users, how would I determine what are the commons books?

```
users: id, first_name, last_name
books: id, name
books_users: book_id, user_id
```

Designer Output, something like:

```
book | count
radBookName | 22
SemiRad | 22
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems want simple `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT b.name, count(*) as user_count
FROM books b INNER JOIN
     books_users bu
     ON bu.book_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.name;
```

This would produce duplicate count if one book has same user, if you want unique count then use `count(distinct bu.user_id)` instead.

Comment: What is = b.IS?

Comment: @AnnaSm. . . `b.IS` is just typo it is actually `b.id`.